flutter stack with clip.none cause dont work ontap
    import 'package:gap/gap.dart';
import 'package:mubu/core/constants/image_constants.dart';
import 'package:mubu/core/constants/text_styles.dart';
import 'package:mubu/core/extension/context_extension.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class Header extends StatelessWidget {
  const Header({
    super.key,
  });

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 250,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: context.primaryColor,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        // Left Background Image
        Positioned(
          top: 45,
          left: 0,
          child: AbsorbPointer(
            child: Image.asset(
              ImageConstants.leftBackground,
              width: 200,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        // Right Background Image
        Positioned(
          top: 50,
          right: 0,
          child: Image.asset(
            ImageConstants.rightBackground,
            width: 95,
          ),
        ),

        Positioned(
          top: 50,
          left: 20,
          right: 20,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              const Row(
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 25,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/29775859?v=4'),
                  ),
                  Gap(17),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Hoşgeldin',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, height: 0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Hira Aker',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24,
                          height: 0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    ImageConstants.notification,
                    width: 34,
                    height: 34,
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 2,
                    right: 2,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 12,
                      height: 12,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xFF13B3B3),
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

        Positioned(
          top: 130,
          left: 20,
          right: 20,
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color(0xFF6924FC).withOpacity(0.95),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  offset: const Offset(0, 3),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Cüzdanım",
                  style: TextStyles.title.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                const Gap(10),
                Text(
                  "Güncel Bakiye",
                  style: TextStyles.bodyLarge.copyWith(
                    color: const Color(0XFFFBBE84),
                  ),
                ),
                const Gap(10),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text("₺13.543,56", style: TextStyles.title.copyWith(color: Colors.white)),
                    Image.asset(
                      ImageConstants.visibilityOff,
                      width: 35,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                    behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                    onTap: () {
                      print("data tapped");
                    },
                    child: Text("data"))
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}

Ontap does not work when going outside the 250 height area. I tried using Inkwell, changing the behavior of the gesture detector, using an absorb pointer, but I couldn't get any results.OnTap functions of parts with clip.none do not work.Translucent behavior or any widget cannot solve this, what can I do?

The issue occurs because of how Flutter handles hit testing for gestures, especially when using clipBehavior: Clip.none in combination with Stack. When a widget extends beyond the bounds of its parent container, Flutter might not register taps outside the original container's bounds.
Solution: Use IgnorePointer with HitTestBehavior.translucent

Ensure that the parent container or widget (in this case, the Stack)
doesn't block gestures for the parts extending outside the defined area.

Replace AbsorbPointer with IgnorePointer and set the hitTestBehavior to translucent for the GestureDetector.
class Header extends StatelessWidget {
  const Header({
    super.key,
  });
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      clipBehavior: Clip.none,
      alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 250,
          width: double.infinity,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            color: context.primaryColor,
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(20),
              bottomRight: Radius.circular(20),
            ),
          ),
        ),
        // Left Background Image
        Positioned(
          top: 45,
          left: 0,
          child: IgnorePointer(
            ignoring: true,
            child: Image.asset(
              ImageConstants.leftBackground,
              width: 200,
            ),
          ),
        ),

        // Right Background Image
        Positioned(
          top: 50,
          right: 0,
          child: Image.asset(
            ImageConstants.rightBackground,
            width: 95,
          ),
        ),

        Positioned(
          top: 50,
          left: 20,
          right: 20,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: [
              const Row(
                children: [
                  CircleAvatar(
                    radius: 25,
                    backgroundImage: NetworkImage('https://avatars.githubusercontent.com/u/29775859?v=4'),
                  ),
                  Gap(17),
                  Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                        'Hoşgeldin',
                        style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 17, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, height: 0),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        'Hira Aker',
                        style: TextStyle(
                          color: Colors.white,
                          fontSize: 24,
                          height: 0,
                          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                        ),
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ],
              ),
              Stack(
                children: [
                  Image.asset(
                    ImageConstants.notification,
                    width: 34,
                    height: 34,
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 2,
                    right: 2,
                    child: Container(
                      width: 12,
                      height: 12,
                      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
                        color: Color(0xFF13B3B3),
                        shape: BoxShape.circle,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                ],
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),

        Positioned(
          top: 130,
          left: 20,
          right: 20,
          child: Container(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 20, vertical: 20),
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              color: const Color(0xFF6924FC).withOpacity(0.95),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15),
              boxShadow: [
                BoxShadow(
                  color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.3),
                  blurRadius: 10,
                  offset: const Offset(0, 3),
                ),
              ],
            ),
            child: Column(
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: [
                Text(
                  "Cüzdanım",
                  style: TextStyles.title.copyWith(color: Colors.white),
                ),
                const Gap(10),
                Text(
                  "Güncel Bakiye",
                  style: TextStyles.bodyLarge.copyWith(
                    color: const Color(0XFFFBBE84),
                  ),
                ),
                const Gap(10),
                Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: [
                    Text("₺13.543,56", style: TextStyles.title.copyWith(color: Colors.white)),
                    Image.asset(
                      ImageConstants.visibilityOff,
                      width: 35,
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                GestureDetector(
                  behavior: HitTestBehavior.translucent,
                  onTap: () {
                    print("data tapped");
                  },
                  child: Text("data"),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}






That solution doesn't work, I solved with this package https://pub.dev/packages/defer_pointer
